# Problem with hyperlinks in visio services

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visio-services, visio

I draw some diagram in Visio Services and map shape data with data from sharepoint list. One of fields is hyperlink. When I view toggle shape information, I can see my hyperlink, but when I try to click them - I see strange URL like "http://mylink,http://mylink" (if I have no link description in list), or "http://mylink,description" (if have). Both of links are not correct. I've try to found solutuion and've found the same question here: http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=2151.0, but that doesn't helps.

Could anyone please help to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the "URL, description" format is explained by [SPListItem Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx). See the URL entry in the mapping table.

This can be 'fixed' with javascript. When the shape is clicked a shapeselectionchanged event is raised (see [Vwa.VwaControl.addHandler Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394484.aspx)). Write an event handler for shapeselectionchanged that simulates the hyperlink being clicked by opening the page (e.g. using window.open).

The javascript can be dropped onto the page using a Content Editor web part. Hope this helps?

Comment: Your solution is clear and correct. But I have another handler on `shapeselectionchanged` (that adds some overlay). So thanks, but it's doesnt help.